# How to validate P4 path in php using regex?

Tags: php, regex

How do I validate a perforce path as follows in PHP using regex?

Accepted paths:
//somechars (starts with // and not ending with /)
The following are valid paths:

```
//depot/abc/pqr/a23/72-32/abc
//something
//something123
```

The following are invalid paths:

```
///depot      (has to start with // and more more slashes)
//depot/abc/  (cannot end with /)
//depot//test (cannot have // in between)
```

The following is the function I came up with:

```
public function is_path_valid($path) {
  if (!preg_match('/\/\/[A-Za-z0-9\-_\.]+.*[A-Za-z0-9\-_\.]$/',$path) ) {
       return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

It is not correct. Can someone point to what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern you used matches:

- `\/\/[A-Za-z0-9\-_\.]+` There's a `//` followed by at least 1 of `[A-Za-z0-9\-_.]`. However, it could match anywhere in the string, not necessarily at the beggining.
- `.*` Any text allowed in between. That's not what you want, is it?
- `[A-Za-z0-9\-_\.]$` Ends with one of those chars (that part looks OK).

---

Here's what you should validate:

- <kbd>`^//`</kbd> It starts with a `//` (notice the `^` matches the position at the beggining of the line).
- <kbd>`[-.\w]+`</kbd> is followed by one or more `-_.A-Za-z0-9` (`\w` is a [shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`)
- <kbd>`(?:/[-.\w]+)*`</kbd> followed by `/` and the same characters as before, repeated 0 or more times (notice `(?: ..)` is a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), and the [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` repeats the whole group).
- <kbd>`$`</kbd> Until the end of the line.

**Regex:**

```
if (!preg_match('~^//[-.\w]+(?:/[-.\w]+)*$~',$path) ) {
```

- <kbd>[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xU8pY9/1)</kbd>

Comment: beat me to it, and with more description than I would've added at first! Very nice! +1

Comment: Thanks. What is "?:" ?

Comment: Regex syntax for [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Consider `(?:foo)` the same as `(foo)`, except it doesn't store unnecessary data. If it were a normal group, `preg_match` would return it as an independent item of the array in 3rd parameter (not used here).